# Change Settings per Object, using 1 Material

Tags: animation, shaders, emission

The idea is that I want certain objects to light up at different keyed times.  However, the objects will all use the same material; it's settings will just vary per object at different times during the animation.

How can I do this using one material?  Is it even possible?
I have seen a similar question but it is not identical to this one, because it requires more than one material.

Comment: @RBlong2us: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do this e.g. with this node tree:

[image]

The value is just keyframed from frame 1 to 250 with values 1 to 250.
And i just add the frame with the y-location (with some calculations) and so i got different colors for my two objects on different frames.

result:

[image]

[image]

https://youtu.be/OkoA8kQhqQ4